# How to show $7^{th}$ degree polynomial is non-positive in $[0,1]$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $0\le x\le 1$, show that  inequality
>   $$99x^7-381x^6+225x^5-415x^4+157x^3-3x^2-x-1\le 0$$

This problem comes from the fact that I solved a different inequality.I tried to solve it by factorizing it to see if I could get symbols.but I failed.

this inequality is hold by [wolfapha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99x%5E7-381x%5E6%2B225x%5E5-415x%5E4%2B157x%5E3-3x%5E2-x-1) Test it.

Comment: Not sure this helps, but here's what the part closest to the $x$-axis looks like for $x < 1$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99x%5E7-381x%5E6%2B225x%5E5-415x%5E4%2B157x%5E3-3x%5E2-x-1,+-.2%3Cx%3C.4

Comment: How about using Sturm's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem and show that the polynomial does not have real roots in the interval (0,1]?

Answer (score 5):

Because by AM-GM $$1+x+3x^2-157x^3+415x^4-225x^5+381x^6-99x^7=$$
$$=1+x+3x^2-157x^3+370x^4+x^4(45-225x+282x^2)+99x^6(1-x)\geq$$
$$\geq370x^4+3x^2+x+1-157x^3=6\cdot\frac{185}{3}x^4+3x^2+x+1-157x^3\ge$$
$$\geq9\sqrt[9]{\left(\frac{185}{3}x^4\right)^6\cdot3x^2\cdot x\cdot1}-157x^3=\left(9\sqrt[9]{\left(\frac{185}{3}\right)^6\cdot3}-157\right)x^3\geq0.$$